# Does it make any sense to store a user as an object?

Tags: php, mysql, oop, authentication

This question might sound strange, but I have a simply tiny session-based login system (PHP+MySQL) for one of my projects, and I was wondering if it would make any sense to store a user in an object. I could imagine such situations, where doing this could be useful, but... I don't really know. Does it make difference in case of let's say a microblogging system?

I think there could be a `User` class defined, with properties loaded from the MySQL tables, and it could have methods/functions like `getUserName()` or `logOut()` or `addPost()`.

The top reason I asked myself this question, is that I don't have a single clue about how to pass an object to the session, plus all this object-oriented stuff is a little bit new for me as well. I'm not entirely sure about when to think with OOP and when to not.

If you could give me some advices about the topic, or anything useful, it would be extremely helpful. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since there is no significant overhead for objects in PHP 5.3/5.4, I would recommend you to write code in object oriented style for everything, except simple experiments in codepad.

As for the authentication system, i wold split it up in two parts:

- [domain object](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?DomainObject), that contains all of your user validation logic
- [data mapper](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/dataMapper.html), that can save `User` instance to DB

Here is a simple API example that you might try to use as basis for your code:

```
$user = new User;
$mapper = new UserMapper( $pdo );

$user->setName( $_POST['username'] );
$mapper->fetch( $user ); 

if ( $user->isAvailable() && $user->matchPassword( $_POST['password'] ))
{
    $user->setLastLogin( time() );
    // here you put interaction with session
}
else
{
    $user->addFailedAttempt();
    if ( $user->getAttempts() >= 5 )
    {
        $user->setStatus( User::STATUS_LOCKED );
    }
}

$mapper->store( $user );
```

You have to understand that the aim of OOP is the maintainability and readability of the code. I assume that you can figure out what goes on in that code snipped without seeing the exact implementation of each method.

Comment: it is actually customary to explain the downvote for an accepted answer.

Comment: So would you recommend that a Current_user class which logs a user in extends a User class?

Comment: How exactly did you manage to arrive to that conclusion. If you read the post you would notice, that the `User` in give example is not "logging" anything. Whether user is "current" or not, shouldn't be determined by user instance itself.

Answer (score 0):

Using classes will make your code more readable and easier to change/modify/upgrade. Also it will reduce code size. But you can also define does functions in a php file without having a class or OOP, just functions and include them everytime you need them. If you use classes it will be easier to pass data in entire web application between functions, entire user object will be as an object. Classes has no effect in performance at all. That's all I have to tell for now.

Answer (score 0):

First of all to answer your question: I would store only those information needed to find the user in the database. If you can load it through your database you could also instantiate a new user object each request which I think is better because data could change and if user data changes you have to update your database AND your session. So load your user from database and create an instance on each request.

Second: Take a look at some sort of orm (Object-Relational-Mapping system) like doctrine2 or similar. Those systems do exactly what you want with your user object.

Comment: If someone is going for an application with small footprint, then using a 3rd party ORM would be the **wrong** thing to do.